# Linq Queries throwing "System.Aggregate" exception

Tags: c#, linq

I am running a Database first Entity Framework application that's using Linq. Certain queries I have run perfectly and return the proper data, but some queries return :

```
A first chance exception of type 'System.AggregateException' occurred in mscorlib.dll
    System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. ---> System.ServiceModel.FaultException: The server was unable to process the request due to an internal error.  For more information about the error, either turn on IncludeExceptionDetailInFaults (either from ServiceBehaviorAttribute or from the  configuration behavior) on the server in order to send the exception information back to the client, or turn on tracing as per the Microsoft .NET Framework SDK documentation and inspect the server trace logs.
       at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.ThrowIfFaultUnderstood(Message reply, MessageFault fault, String action, MessageVersion version, FaultConverter faultConverter)
       at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.HandleReply(ProxyOperationRuntime operation, ProxyRpc& rpc)
       at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.EndCall(String action, Object[] outs, IAsyncResult result)
       at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.TaskCreator.c__DisplayClass5`1.b__4(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
       at System.Threading.Tasks.TaskFactory`1.FromAsyncCoreLogic(IAsyncResult iar, Func`2 endFunction, Action`1 endAction, Task`1 promise, Boolean requiresSynchronization)
```

Any idea why this is? Is it linked to null data returned? How can I find out more about this error?

Here is one of the queries that causes the error :

```
var meetingDetails = ctx.MEETING.Join(ctx.MASTER.Where(i => i.STATUS == "CURRENT"
                    && i.DOC_CLASS == "MEETING"),
                i => new { i.REVISION, i.DOC_NUMBER },
                d => new { d.REVISION, d.DOC_NUMBER },
                (i, d) => new Meeting
                {
                    Id = i.ID,

                })
                .OrderBy(x => x.StartDate)
                .Distinct()
                .FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: Have you some calls for `TaskFactory.FromAsync`?

Comment: "My house burned down, any idea why this is?" You need to provide a bit more context, sir.

Comment: Sorry guys, thought it might have been a common issue, posted a query that causes the problems

Answer (score 0):

`AggregateException` is thrown when at least one task has an unhandled exception. Because you can have multiple parallel tasks all unhandled exceptions are aggregated into a single exception. Inside the aggregate you have a `FaultException` which indicates a WCF error. The description of the error is:

> The server was unable to process the request due to an internal error.  For more information about the error, either turn on IncludeExceptionDetailInFaults (either from ServiceBehaviorAttribute or from the  configuration behavior) on the server in order to send the exception information back to the client, or turn on tracing as per the Microsoft .NET Framework SDK documentation and inspect the server trace logs.

So you have a WCF error but you do not know what happened on the server side. You will have to follow the instructions provided in the error description to get more details about the source of your error.